# how to all Oracle Stored Proc in Package from Delphi

Tags: delphi, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have been given a stored procedure (developed by a 3rd party) to execute...

```
create or replace package body cux_ivr_task_assigupd_pkg is
  -- Private type declarations
  procedure cux_update_task_assgnments(
    p_task_number    in varchar2,
    p_pressed_number in number,
    x_err_code       out varchar2,
    x_err_message    out varchar2) is
```

and trying to execute this procedure from a Delphi program. when trying to call with name cux_ivr_task_assigupd_pkg.cux_update_task_assgnments I get error

> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06564: object
>   CUX_IVR_TASK_ASSIGUPD_PKG.CUX_UPDATE_TASK_ASSGNMENTS does not exist
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DESCRIBE", line 117 ORA-06512: at line 1

and if I use name cux_update_task_assgnments then get error

> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00201: identifier
>   'CUX_UPDATE_TASK_ASSGNMENTS' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1,
>   column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I do not have access to the database itself - I am just a client that needs to be able to execute the procedure. I tried both names, as the people that manage the databases told me to try it one and then the other. So I not sure if it is permission related or ???

Ideally I would like to execute using an ADO command line

exec procedure-name(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)

but only error about incorrect syntax and the people responsible for the DB could not help?!?

Any clues about the above error?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it a support query and should be directed to the vendor.

Comment: You are either not logging on to the correct schema to execute this package or you don't have permissions to execute it from the schema you're logged into. As you don't have direct access there's nothing we can do to help. It sounds like you're paying for this - so get your money's worth and ask the company you bought this off.

Comment: Ben, thanks for that. I have already tried the "vendor" and that was why I came here. I was just after some sort of confirmation that the errors indicated something on their end was amiss. (I am not an SQL dummy yet :P having worked with MSSQL, mysql, D2B2, interbase). this one just has me stumped!

Comment: Ask your vendor to check that you(or your connecting user) has permission to execute procedures in that package.  The terminology is 'Do I have `GRANT EXECUTE` on the package?'

Comment: The puzzle here, for me, is how `SYS.DBMS_DESCRIBE` is involved.  I think it is unlikely that Delphi has anything to do with it; are you able to execute the procedure from `SQL Plus`?

Comment: Ask also you vendor whether or not this procedure is defined only in the package body, or it's on the package declaration too. If it's not in the declaration you won't be able to use it.